# Libpqxx throws many DLL errors

Tags: c++, libpq, libpqxx

I tried using

https://en.wiki.imlint.org/Pqxx_tutorial

to use postgres 14 and cpp.

I followed the steps in there and I'm trying to run the code from the website but I'm getting DLLs errors. I've already tried to add them from sites likes dll-files.com but I always get another error. The errors are always about something which contains lib so I suspect there might be something wrong with the linking.

Here are my project's settings:

[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzpPQ.png)

[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhXPS.png)

[photo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIYMN.png)

libpqxx lib directory content:

```
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib>dir /s /b /o:gn
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\cmake
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\pkgconfig
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\pqxx.lib
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\cmake\libpqxx
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\cmake\libpqxx\libpqxx-config.cmake
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\cmake\libpqxx\libpqxx-config-version.cmake
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\cmake\libpqxx\libpqxx-targets.cmake
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\cmake\libpqxx\libpqxx-targets-release.cmake
C:\Twitter\libpqxx\lib\pkgconfig\libpqxx.pc
```

and here is one of the errors I get:
[photo4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33vyA.png)

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you install the prerequisite libraries like libwinpthread from the error dialog?

Comment: Do the dlls mentioned in the error box exist on your system? If so did you put them in the same directory as your executable or in a folder listed in your window `PATH` environment variable?